# Trouble with my Wiki Search Bar - Can't get the search to work properly

Tags: django, search, wikipedia, wiki

I am creating a Wiki page and I can't get my search bar to function properly. When I try to search for "python" or "django" for example I am taken to a page with the address "http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/". It looks exactly like my home page but does not have any of my Headings.

Here is my urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("search/", views.search, name="search"),
    path("wiki/<str:title>", views.title, name="title"),
    path("edit/<str:title>", views.edit, name="edit"),
    
]
```

In views.py here is my search request:

```
def search(request):
    search_key = request.POST.get("q", "")
    
    entries = util.list_entries()
    exists = search_key in entries
    
    if exists:
        return redirect('title', title=search_key)

    filtered_entries = [entry for entry in entries if not entry.find(search_key) == -1]

    return render(request, "encyclopedia/index.html", {
        "entries": filtered_entries
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the file's path you're rendering in order to execute correctly.

Use:

```py
 render (request, "encyclopedia/search.html", {
       # your code go here
}
```